# "text" parameter in pinecone call from langchain

Tags: python, nlp, word-embeddings, language-model, vector-database

In [this tutorial](https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/vectorstores/pinecone), I do not understand what "text" refers to

```
vectorstore = Pinecone(index, embeddings.embed_query, "text")
```

Could you please help?